# Bash multiple parameter substitution

Tags: bash, environment-variables

I'm looking to set the value of a variable to one thing if it was already set or another if it was not. Here's an example of what I mean

```bash
export RESULT=${VALID:+Yes:-No}
```

Where the value of `${VALID:+Yes:-No}` would be `Yes` if the variable was set or `No` if it was not.

One way I can do it now:

```bash
if [ -n "${VALID}" ]; then
  export RESULT=Yes
else
  export RESULT=No
fi
```

I *could* do it like this, but it would be nice to have a "one-liner".

Is it possible to do this in one line?

Comment: It might be of some interest to note that *zsh* will give the desired result with an expression like `${${VALID:+Yes}:-No}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One line, requirement met:

```bash
export RESULT=$([ -n "$VALID" ] && echo Yes || echo No)
```

Comment: thanks Jack who edited, proposing an even shorter one-liner than my original answer.

Comment: Forking a new shell is an expensive way to avoid a single line of code.

Comment: Also, if you're going to allow an `...&&...||...` construct, you may as well just write `[ -n "$VALID" ] && export RESULT=Yes || export RESULT=No`.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to do multiple parameter expansions within one variable assignement.

Without using an `if` statement, you can just use a couple of parameter expansions.

```
$ VALID="aaa"
$ RESULT="${VALID:+Yes}"; RESULT="${RESULT:-No}"; echo $RESULT
Yes
$ VALID=""
$ RESULT="${VALID:+Yes}"; RESULT="${RESULT:-No}"; echo $RESULT
No
```

It's not a single statement, but it's short enough that it fits on one line without the complexity of a subshell and `if`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an array with 2 elements `(no yes)` and based on variable's length decide which value to be returned:

```
# variable set case
>>> VALID=foo
>>> arr=(no yes) && echo "${arr[$((${#VALID} > 0))]}"    
yes

# variable not set
>>> unset VALID
>>> arr=(no yes) && echo "${arr[$((${#VALID} > 0))]}"    
no
```

Answer (score 1):

The `-v VAR` printf option is a bash extension. Without it, you could use command substitution. (Variable names deliberately down-cased.)

```
printf -v result %.3s ${valid:+YES}NO
```